# I do not understand the SymPy Mechanics rolling disc example

Tags: sympy

In the example [A rolling disc using Lagrange’s Method](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/mechanics/examples/rollingdisc_example_lagrange.html) of the Sympy>Mechanics module it creates a contact point C between the disc and ground, and sets to 0 the velocity of C in the N reference frame, wich represents the floor.

```
C.set_vel(N, 0)
```

But, as I see it, the contact point C is moving as the disc rolls over the floor, so the velocity of C in N should be non null, and in fact it should be one of the outputs of the example. What am I missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics, not programming.

Comment: In particular, see [What do people actually mean by “rolling without slipping”?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64555/what-do-people-actually-mean-by-rolling-without-slipping)

Comment: OK, thanks for the link, it was very hepful. I understand now